# React one button to submit multiple forms with different functionalities

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to build a page that the user can add/remove multiple small forms, and each form sends the request to different API. Is it possible to have one button to triggers all onSubmit events for each form?

```
<form id="form1">
    <input name="field1" type="text" />
</form>
<form id="form2">
    <input name="field2" type="text" />
</form>
<form id="form3">
    <input name="field3" type="text" />
</form>

<button>Submit</button>
```

Like when you click the submit button in the parent component, the onSubmit function for each child component will be called?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I find the solution.
So create a list of Ref() of child component, and when the button is clicked in parent component, we loop through the child Refs, and let child to send request to backend